# fglrx driver installation failure

Tags: driver, failed-installation, amd-processor

I manually install  Catalyst 12.4 with methods in [hwoto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI).
The installation doesn't throw errors, while when I types the command

```
fglrxinfo
```

I got the following error

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  138 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
Serial number of failed request:  13
Current serial number in output stream:  13
```

I also tried to use the Ubuntu repositories to add additional drivers, while it always fail to install the driver.

And the following messages seems to indicate that fglrx was already installed,
how to fix this problem?

```
itsuper7@ubuntu:/host/Dropbox$ aptitude search fglrx
i   fglrx                           - Video driver for the AMD graphics accelera
iBA fglrx-amdcccle                  - Catalyst Control Center for the AMD graphi
pB  fglrx-amdcccle-updates          - Catalyst Control Center for the AMD graphi
v   fglrx-control                   -                                           
p   fglrx-dev                       - Video driver for the AMD graphics accelera
v   fglrx-driver                    -                                           
v   fglrx-driver-dev                -                                           
c   fglrx-updates                   - Video driver for the AMD graphics accelera
pB  fglrx-updates-dev               - Video driver for the AMD graphics accelera
```

Comment: I had the same problem and found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11387260#post11387260), it might help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and fix it with a symLink

sudo ln -s /usr/include/fglrx /usr/lib64/fglrx

but it depends from where your fglrx installed